# WinRar said wrong password

Tags: passwords, winrar

The thing is that, I'm very sure I used the right password. I made the file myself, and often changing what's inside that rar, and before it always worked with no problem at all using that password. But now suddenly it can't be opened, always said Wrong Password. Caps-lock off, I even typed the pass and copy-paste it, yet still wrong. And it's only said "Wrong Password, no files to extract". How could this happen?

Comment: The most likely case.  You actually have the wrong password.  Its also possible the archive is corrupt.  Why was this tagged as Windows 8?

Comment: Oh god corrupt... Eh, because my OS win8. Sorry, I'll remove it.

Comment: Like I said;  The more likely case;  You actually have the wrong password.

Comment: Wrong keyboard layout? Either while entering the password now, or while setting the original password.

Comment: I just opened and edited it yesterday using that password... I suspected I did something wrong when saving or closing the editing program... It's more than 10 characters, seems I've gotta give up -_-